# What is equivalent to LayerDrawable.SetLayerInsetRight in versions before 23?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am developing custom renderer for android and using `LayerDrawable.SetLayerInsetRight` method and works fine but that method is added in API level 23 and I am wondering what is equivalent to it in versions before 23?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my research, you could use [this method](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Graphics.Drawables.LayerDrawable.SetLayerInset/p/System.Int32/System.Int32/System.Int32/System.Int32/System.Int32/)
`SetLayerInset (Int32 index, Int32 l, Int32 t, Int32 r, Int32 b)`
 in versions before 23, this method was added in API level 1.

For example, if you set the `layerDrawable.SetLayerInsetRight(1,30);`in versions 23 or higher,you could set `layerDrawable.SetLayerInset(1,0,0,30,0);` in versions before 23